# Merge two arrays by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, angularjs-directive

I have a specific cuestion about merge arrays:

I'm using google charts and I need to do something like this

[Combo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)
[image]

To do something like that I need to fill this matrix
[image]

I did fine with axis x and axis y:

```
$scope.data= [];
            $scope.data[0]= ['Months'];

            angular.forEach($scope.consultors, function(consultor) {
                $scope.data[0].push(consultor.no_user);
            })

            angular.forEach(months, function(month) {
                $scope.data.push([month])
            })
```

[image]

but, my problem is when i try to put `$scope.relatorias`, inside of $scope.data.

This is `$scope.relatorias`, this variable has the data of every consultor group by month, like this:

[image]

If you open each array look like this

[image]

I just need push ganancias_netas, but my problem is when there is an empty month, for example **anapaula** has data in every month but **renato** hasn't.

I have try to user for or for each but is doesn't work, I'm not an expert in matrix and this is my first time working on it.

fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rfcabal/5ftw7c8d/

/// UPDATE ///

I added this code that first fill with 0 $scope.data and then search for the values in relatorios and shoudl fill $scope.data, but for some reason jus fill with the last found value.

```
for (var i = 1; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                for (var a = 1; a < $scope.data[0].length; a++) {
                    $scope.data[i][a] = 0;
                    for (var b = 0; b < $scope.relatorios[a-1].length; b++) {
                        console.log(a-1+' '+b+' '+3);
                        console.log($scope.relatorios[a-1][b]['ganancias_netas'])
                        $scope.data[i][a] = $scope.relatorios[a-1][b]['ganancias_netas'];                   
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is that you only have array index to operate on. There's no information about the month in these objects. That's doable to fill missing months with 0s or whatever you need, but you need to have the information about the month. So the object should have additional property like number of the month: `{month: 3, co_usuario: '...', no_usuario: '...', ...}`

Comment: In fact in $scope.relatorias there are dates, it's called fecha_emision, I didn't realize that the picture was not showing it. Sorry I added a new picture.

Comment: Can you provide real data in JSFiddle for example? These two arrays that you want to combine. It's gonna be easier to explain it on the data you have.

Comment: I will as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: now the JSFiddle works good http://fiddle.jshell.net/rfcabal/5ftw7c8d/

Comment: And what should be the desired output from these arrays? Can you add it there in the fiddle?

Comment: $scope.relatorio should be inside of data but only the data ganacias_netas  in relation to the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved with 2 for

First i fill every data space with 0

```
for (var i = 1; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                for (var a = 1; a < $scope.data[0].length; a++) {
                    $scope.data[i][a] = 0;
                }
            }
```

The i jus remplace where fecha_emision equal to position 1 of every array.

```
for (var a = 0; a < $scope.relatorios.length; a++) {
                for (var b = 0; b < $scope.relatorios[a].length; b++) {
                    for (var i = 1; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                        var index = $scope.data[i].indexOf($scope.relatorios[a][b]['fecha_emision']);
                        if(index >= 0) {
                            $scope.data[i][a+1] = parseFloat($scope.relatorios[a][b]['ganancias_netas']);
                        }
                    }
                }                                       
            }
```